# The splash image is said to be small on other devices

Tags: flutter, splash-screen, android-12

The splash image is said to be small on other devices. How should I correct this part? I'm new to flutter, so I need help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3nSF.png)

I tried searching and resizing the image, but it was not fixed.

Comment: Do you have different images for each device display DPI you're targeting? Or can you use vector artwork instead?

Comment: First of all, thank you for your reply.

Each device display DPI you target has a different image.

If the Android version is different, does the image come out small?